# moment().add() only works with literal values

Tags: angular, typescript, momentjs

I'm using Moment.js in TypeScript (under Angular 2 if that matters).  When I use the add() method with literal values as arguments, it works fine:

```
moment().add(1, 'month');
```

However, if I try to replace the units with a string, it fails:

```
let units:string = 'month';
moment().add(1, units);
```

with this error:

```
Argument of type '1' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DurationConstructor'.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I am using this same code in my angular 2 typescript app and it works. The problem must be somewhere else in your code I believe

Comment: Hmm, strange. Thanks for trying it out.  I will keep poking at it...

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Deprecated reverse overload `add(unit: unitOfTime.DurationConstructor, amount: number|string)` creates ambiguity.

You can fix this by defining type of `units` to be `DurationConstructor` instead of `string`:

```
let units: moment.unitOfTime.DurationConstructor = 'month';
moment().add(1, units);
```

Another option is just to use `const` instead of `let`, so literal type will be inferred:

```
const units = 'month';
moment().add(1, units);
```

Comment: Your example works, but how could I assign something of type string to the units variable?  For example, if I have a function that takes in the units as a string and want to pass it to moment().add()?  Something like this:

`function addOneUnit(date: Date, units: string) {
    let m = moment(date);
    return m.add(1, units);

Comment: `DurationConstructor` is a union of string literal types (like `type Foo = 'month' | 'week' | ...`), it keeps you from passing invalid/not supported strings as unit parameter. So you'd better change function signature to `addOneUnit(date: Date, units:moment.unitOfTime.DurationConstructor)`. Another option is to use type assertion (`units as moment.unitOfTime.DurationConstructor`) - but you'll lose type safety.

Answer (score 9):

Another option to the accepted answer is typecasting in the argument. There's really no difference, just figured I'd include this answer as an option. Also unitOfTime can be imported from moment as a module if you want some more brevity.

```
import { unitOfTime } from 'moment';
import * as moment from 'moment';

option = {val: 30, unit: 'm'}
moment().add( this.querySince.val, <unitOfTime.DurationConstructor>this.querySince.unit )
```

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, none of the above answers worked with me!
But this only made the charm! :D

```
const startTime = moment().subtract(this.time.amount as moment.DurationInputArg1, this.time.unit as moment.DurationInputArg2);
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two declarations of `add`

1. `add(amount?: DurationInputArg1, unit?: DurationInputArg2): Moment;`
2. **Deprecated** `add(unit: unitOfTime.DurationConstructor, amount: number|string)`

When typescript need to match overloads it tries to take closest type. When you've tried to pass `units:string`, closest match `number|string` is **second overload**, because **any string** will match to this declaration, f.e. `'qwe'`, or `'rty'` of type `string`, but not `DurationArg2` which is expected as second parameter in **first declaration**.

When you call `moment.add(1,'months)` it will use **first declaration**, because it is possible to cast `1` to type of the first argument in first signature, but not in the second.

So to fix this issue and similar, you should say what you exactly want to use.

**Example 1. First signature will be used**

```
import * as moment from 'moment'

calculateRangeFromEnd(end: Date, unitsAmount: moment.DurationInputArg1, unitsMeasureMoment: moment.DurationInputArg2): IDateRange {
    return {
      endDate: end,
      startDate: moment(end).subtract(unitsAmount, unitsMeasureMoment).toDate()
    }
  }
```

**Example 2. Second signature will be used**

```
import * as moment from 'moment'

calculateRangeFromEnd(end: Date, unitsAmount: number | string, unitsMeasureMoment: moment.unitOfTimes.DurationConstructor): IDateRange {
    return {
      endDate: end,
      startDate: moment(end).subtract(unitsMeasureMoment, unitsAmount).toDate()
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

This answer is building on all the previous answers that specify `deprecated reverse syntax of add, subtract, etc functions in moment` as the cause of the problem.

I cast the DurationInputArg2 field to `unitOfTime.Base` since all these methods have this as the ultimate superclass and so it means for `add, subtract, startOf, endOf` I just need to remember `as Base`:

```
 import Base = moment.unitOfTime.Base

 theMoment.subtract(amount, unitString as Base)
 theMoment.startOf(unitString as Base)
```

The confusing part for most people is that the `amount` is marked as the error.  Fixed when one qualifies the units.

Answer (score 2):

The problem in my case was that I was using `mins`. The type def for DurationConstructor is

```
namespace unitOfTime {
type Base = (
  "year" | "years" | "y" |
  "month" | "months" | "M" |
  "week" | "weeks" | "w" |
  "day" | "days" | "d" |
  "hour" | "hours" | "h" |
  "minute" | "minutes" | "m" |
  "second" | "seconds" | "s" |
  "millisecond" | "milliseconds" | "ms"
);
```

So this works out of the box:

```
refTime.clone().subtract(15, 'minute')
```

-k

Comment: This was my problem as well. I was using 'min' instead of 'minute'. Very unhelpful error.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused by deprecated reverse syntax of add, subtract, etc functions in moment library. Below is an excerpt:

moment.d.ts

```
add(amount?: DurationInputArg1, unit?: DurationInputArg2): Moment;
/**
 * @deprecated reverse syntax
 */
add(unit: unitOfTime.DurationConstructor, amount: number|string): Moment;
```

In my case I wanted units and value both to be variables so I had to write a function to convert the `general` string to the acceptable ones ("hours", "minutes", etc.).

```
function convertToDuration (unit: string): Moment.unitOfTime.DurationConstructor {

if(unit ==  'seconds' || unit ==  'minutes' || unit ==  'hours' || unit ==  'days' || unit ==  'weeks' || unit ==  'months'){
    return unit;
}
else // Default unit is hours
    return 'hours';
}
```

Now to call this function:

```
const time = moment().add(expiryTime.value, convertToDuration(expiryTime.unit));
```

Definition of expiryTime in TypeScript:

```
interface ExpiryTimeDef {
value: number,
unit: string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change type definition from `let` into `const`

```
const units = 'month';
moment().add(1, units);
```

this works for me..