# Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DurationConstructor

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, momentjs

I'm using Moment.js in TypeScript (under Angular 7 if that matters). When I use the `subtract()` method with literal values as arguments, it works fine but when I replace it with a string or a number I get an alert saying

> **Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to a parameter of type 'DurationConstructor'**.

This is my code:

```
const min: number = moment()
    .subtract(this.relativeDateRange.quantity,this.relativeDateRange.interval)
    .valueOf();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [moment().add() only works with literal values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41768864/moment-add-only-works-with-literal-values)